# HAproxy for postfix

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix, smtp, load-balancing, haproxy

I want to setup HA postfix mail servers with 2 postfix instances.  I have two postfix servers and I configured two postfix instances on these servers. Now I want to know how to configure HAproxy loadbalancer for the backend postfix servers. Can somebody provide info or useful documentation to configure HAproxy for postfix.

Comment: I have done all other things except HAproxy. I would like to know how to configure HAproxy for postfix.

Comment: No, I mean, what HAproxy configurations have you tried?  Have you googled anything about HAProxy and SMTP and made a guess at how a configuration might look?   I searched for HAProxy SMTP and got this http://www.linickx.com/645/load-balance-anything-with-haproxy

Comment: Alternatively, forget about usng haproxy and set up the other server in dns as a backup by entering in another mx record and a lower priority.

Comment: SMTP is such a batchy protocol I fail to see why you would need this unless you were expecting hundreds of emails a second. Just setup multiple MX records.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to run haproxy in tcp mode. Something like this should work:

```
frontend smtp_in *:25
    mode                tcp
    default_backend     smtp_out

backend smtp_out
    balance leastconn
    server  smtp-server-1.domain.com  smtp-server-1.domain.com:25
    server  smtp-server-2.domain.com  smtp-server-2.domain.com:25
    server  smtp-server-3.domain.com  smtp-server-3.domain.com:25
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you use haproxy 1.5-dev and postfix >= 2.10, you can use the PROXY protocol between the two so that postfix can get the original client's address even through postscreen.